# Touch to Stop scrolling on listview does not work

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Suppose that I have 100 item in my listView. When I scroll up and down, and I try to touch to stop the scrolling. But it's not work. It scroll until it reach the item of the first scroll touch.

Is it the phone problem or my app missing some implementing ?

Answer (score 0):

public class OnTouchListner implements OnTouchListener{

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
             {
                businessResultListView.smoothScrollBy(0, 0); 
                return true;

            }  
         return false;
    }
 }
```

and call it:

businessResultListView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListner());